# Can't compress-Archive from UNC path

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to make a script that will automaticly find the correct folder on a network drive. These are our users' homefolders.

I want to zip the specified folder and place it somewhere else.

I keep getting an error that access is denied on the network drive when the zipping proces start.

I tried running elevated powershell, but the same error occurs.
Here is the script I made:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null 
$username = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Name ")

$source=Get-ChildItem -Path \\server\Home1, \\server\Home2, \\server\Home3 -Include $username | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

$destination = "C:\testzippowershell\"+$username+".zip"

Compress-Archive -literalpath $source -DestinationPath $destination
```

These are the resulting errors:

> Get-ChildItem : The specified network name is no longer available. At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:663
>   char:20 + $dirContents = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceDirPath
>   -Recurse + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ReadError: (\server\Home3\user\Desktop:String)
>   [Get-ChildItem], IOException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
>   Get-ChildItem : The specified network name is no longer available. At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:663
>   char:20 + $dirContents = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceDirPath
>   -Recurse + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ReadError: (\server\Home3\user\Documents:String)
>   [Get-ChildItem], IOException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
>   Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\testzippowershell\user.zip' because
>   it does not exist. At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:233
>   char:21 + ... Remove-Item -LiteralPath $DestinationPath -Force
>   -Recurse ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\testzippowershell\user.zip:String)
>   [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand Exception
>   calling "GetFiles" with "0" argument(s): "The specified network name
>   is no longer available. " At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:677
>   char:13 + $files = $currentContent.GetFiles() +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:)
>   [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException

Does anyone know how to get the compress-archive working for a UNC path?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is the current result:
(The single slash is actually double, but get lost when I edit to remove details from my company)

> Get-ChildItem : Access to the path '\server\Home3\user\Desktop' is
>   denied. At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:663
>   char:20
>   +     $dirContents = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceDirPath -Recurse
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\server\Home3\user\Desktop:String) [Get-ChildItem],
>   UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
>   Get-ChildItem : Access to the path '\server\Home3\user\Documents' is
>   denied. At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:663
>   char:20
>   +     $dirContents = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceDirPath -Recurse
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\server\Home3\user\Documents:String) [Get-ChildItem],
>   UnauthorizedAccessException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
>   Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\testzippowershell\user.zip' because
>   it does not exist. At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:233
>   char:21
>   + ...             Remove-Item -LiteralPath $DestinationPath -Force -Recurse ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\testzippowershell\user.zip:String) [Remove-Item],
>   ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
>   Exception calling "GetFiles" with "0" argument(s): "Access to the path
>   '\server\Home3\user\Desktop' is denied." At
>   C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive\Microsoft.PowerShell.Archive.psm1:677
>   char:13
>   +             $files = $currentContent.GetFiles()
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: For me its working, I can compress files from a unc-path. what is the result of test-path -path $source`?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a slash from the start of your UNC path as the error shows `\server\Home3\user\Desktop`, I'm not sure how this is happening though! maybe try putting single quotes around each path?

Comment: If I use -path instead of -literalpath I get these error:                               
                                                                                                              Get-ChildItem : Access to the path '\\server\Home3\user\Desktop' is denied.

Comment: I can get it working with a commandline7ip: [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null 
$username = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Name ")

$source=Get-ChildItem -Path \\server\Home1, \\server\Home2, \\server\Home3 -Include $username | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

$destination = "C:\testzippowershell\"+$username+".zip"

cd $source

C:\temp\7z1604-extra\7za.exe a -t7z $username+".zip"

Comment: I tried the following to test the path, but it seems to be working                  
PS H:\> # PowerShell  Checks If a File Exists
$WantFile = "\\server\Home3\user" 
$FileExists = Test-Path $WantFile 
If ($FileExists -eq $True) {Write-Host "Yippee"}
Else {Write-Host "No file at this location"}
Yippee

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid.

The homedrive I was testing was my own.

I tried with a different and it was working without any issues.